# Set color of text in a Textbox/Label to Red and make it bold

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, text-formatting

I want a text color to be red in color on certain condition.

Here is how  i want to get it done.

```
string minusvalue = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
if (Convert.ToDouble(minusvalue) < 0)
{ 
// set color of text in TextBox1 to red color and bold.
}
```

Is there any function that can set the property of text in TextBox?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
TextBox1.Font.Bold = True;
```

---

Or this can be done using a CssClass **(recommended)**:

```
.highlight
{
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}

TextBox1.CssClass = "highlight";
```

---

Or the styles can be added inline:

```
TextBox1.Attributes["style"] = "color:red; font-weight:bold;";
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the property ForeColor.
Like this :

```
TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string minusvalue = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

if (Convert.ToDouble(minusvalue) < 0)
{ 
    // set color of text in TextBox1 to red color and bold.
    TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it. This approach can be useful for changing the text to 2 different colors, just by adding 2 spans.

```
Label1.Text = "String with original color" + "<b><span style=""color:red;"">" + "Your String Here" + "</span></b>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```css
label { color: red; font-weight:bold;}
label span { color: blue; font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<label>Label With Color <span>And Bold Text</span> </label>
```